# ListView UWP Drag Reorder doesn't fire Drop events

Tags: listview, gridview, drag-and-drop, win-universal-app

I am attempting to reorder a ListView in my UWP project.

```
     <ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="List" Margin="12, 0, 12, 0"
               ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListDataTemplate}" 
               SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="List_ItemClick" 
               AllowDrop="True" CanReorderItems="True" ReorderMode="Enabled"
               DropCompleted="List_DropCompleted" />
```

In Code behind:

```
    private void List_DropCompleted(UIElement sender,DropCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        UseManualOrder = true;
    }
```

The UI Works great. I can drag and reorder with mouse click and drag or touch and drag on phone. However, I cannot get any of the drag/drop events to fire in the code behind. I have tried: Drop; DropCompleted; DragItemsCompleted. None will fire.  I have tried everything I can think of.

My other events in code behind like List_ItemClick are working fine.

Anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: I added CanDragItems="True" and DragItemsCompleted fires just fine for me. For you?

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried: Drop; DropCompleted; DragItemsCompleted. None will fire.

Tested it, [Drop event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.drop.aspx) and [DragItemsCompleted event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.dragitemscompleted.aspx) can get fire. When you use these events, you will need to enable `AllowDrop="True"` and `CanDragItems="True"` for your `ListView`.

Also tested [DropCompleted event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.dropcompleted.aspx) with other controls, this event won't be triggered for now.

But this problem will not affect the Drop and Drag implementation, you can refer to the official [Drag and drop sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop), see how to make them work in this sample.

Comment: Yeah,  I had missed the subtle difference in the naming of DragStarting and DragItemsStartings.  Thanks